# What is the difference between bubble sort and balloon sort in java programming

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

what is the main difference using bubble and balloon sort, and also gnome sort, with examples if possible?
If I had this array

`arr = [9,10,5,6,4,7,8,1,2]`

what would be the difference when using those different methods of sort

Comment: The algorithms are different, being in java makes no difference

Comment: What is a balloon sort?

Comment: @MarcoForberg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome_sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the description from [here](http://www.glennvon.com/2010/10/balloon-sorting-in-c.html)

> The balloon sort is **similar to the bubble sort**, in that it compares elements of the array and swaps those that are not in their proper positions. The difference between these two sorts is the manner in which they compare the elements. The balloon sort compares the first element with each following element of the array, making any necessary swaps.When the first pass through the array is complete, the balloon sort then takes the second element and compares it with each following element of the array swapping elements that are out of order. This sorting process continues until the entire array is ordered.

[Here](http://www.codemiles.com/c-examples/balloon-sort-algorithm-c-implementation-code-sorting-array-t10823.html) , you can find the implementing C++ code.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? Balloon sort is hard to find on the net.

Comment: Added the source link.

Comment: That's what i was searching for